# Magento 301's with PHP code aquire Seo Url?

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I am looking to migrate a website from Cubecart 4 to Magento  1.8. I have created a script that grabs the old cat id from the url, then searches the database to where this is stored (I copied them over) It then grabs the new magento category ID and then needs to grabs the URL of that category. I then want to make a 301 redirect from to the new url.

I cant grab the SEO url from the ID however. So far I can grab the un written url from the id with this where $caturl2 is the category id.

```
Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($caturl2)->getUrl();
```

Is there anyway to grab the seo url by ID? Any ideas?

At the minute it's outputting: /catalog/category/view/s/cat-name/id/4448/

Answer (score 1):

To get the full SEO url, stored in URL rewrite management tables, you should use the follwing code.

```
Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($caturl2)->getUrlPath();
```